# not able to insert values to database from textbox

Tags: c#, database, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            sc.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=C:\DOCUMENTS AND SETTINGS\SUSAN MANEESH\MY DOCUMENTS\DATA.MDF");

                sc.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("connect");

            com.Connection = sc;
            com.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO tabletb(name,dept,desig,place)VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "');");

            try
            {
                int res = com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (res > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("insert");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            sc.Close();




        }
    }
}
```

This code built successfully, but when I execute it. It shows: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server." 
Please tell me what the problem is in this.

Comment: You should use parameters instead of directly injecting the text of your textbox in your SQL Command to prevent SQL Injection

Comment: "please tel me what is the problem" => One of the Problems is that you ask for a solution but don't give the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you specified wrong connection string to your database.

See detailed instructions about connection string format [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: I got confused, will you plz tell the data source path which i given is correct or not

Comment: Do you have access to you database with SQL Management Studio or Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Check [Connectionstrings][1], search for your provider and check if you didn't make any mistakes in your connectionstring.